# converting an array of strings into a simple string and vice-versa in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Lets say, Here is an array of strings in c#:

```
string[] array = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
```

Is there any way to convert this string array into a string like this:

```
 "one,two,three"
```

And after converting into this string, how will I get back the previous array of strings, I mean how will I convert the string into an array of strings again?

```
string[] array = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
```

Comment: use string.join(",", array) to join the string  and use joinedstring.split(',') to get the array back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

**join**

```
var str = string.Join(",", array);
```

**array**

```
var strArr = str.Split(',');
```

[DOTNETFIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0IGGxw)

Comment: how will I display the string in the console? @Anik Islam Abhi

Comment: use a for loop or foreach loop to display in console for `strArr`

Comment: I meant how to display the converted string to console? using Console.Writeline(str); is not working @Anik Islam Abhi

Comment: @xls i have updated my answer. check the fiddle link

Answer (score 2):

Given your array of strings:

```
string[] array = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
```

You can join it like this (there are several other ways, but this is one of the simpler ones)

```
var str = string.Join(",", array);
```

see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) and [dotnetpearls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) for further information on this method which also has some interestiong overoads.

Then you can turn it back to an array using the split method ob your joined string like so:

```
var array2 = str.Split(',');
```

Also, see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) or [dotnetpearls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split) for deeper knowledge on this method.

Answer (score 2):

Your Asnwer is Join and Split will help you to do this

### Join

The string.Join method combines many strings into one. It receives two arguments: an array or IEnumerable and a separator string. It places the separator between every element of the collection in the returned string.

```
string.Join(",", array)
```

### Split

Often strings have delimiter characters in their data. Delimiters include "," the comma and "\t" tab characters.

```
string[] words = JoinedString.Split(',');
```